# "Handler crashed with error runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", but POSTMAN is ok! Why this happens?

Tags: http, axios, authorization, http-post

I work with vue and go for frontend and backend respectively. I send post request to my server and get 403 error code message(notAllowed). But in postman I get the objects and is fine.

**Vue and Vuex**

My axios post request:

```
const response = await this.$axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/v1/org/${params.organization}/kkms/${params.kkm}/closeShift`,{
  headers : { 
     'token' : this.state.token.value
}});
```

I know I should also use other properties like 'Content-Type' and etc in headers, but know it works well with only "token" property in the other requests. I want to know whether problem in backend or frontend?

Comment: You need to show your code and the error encountered as well as a full stack trace.

Comment: That error message looks very much like a typical Go error message. So if your only question is whether it's caused in the backend or frontend, the answer is the backend. But you should know that anyway, based on _where you see the error_. If you actually want help solving the error, you'll need to include the full error message, and the code causing it.

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you! I say to my partner which works on "Go" side

Comment: I never used Go on the server side, but I experienced many times similar problem. Just as a suggestion, take a look if it can be a different domains problem, or try to send the request adding to the axios request options ´axios.get(url, {withCredentials: true})´

Comment: Also, I see you are using axios to make a POST request. When you post, the structure is `axios.post(url,params,options)`, and it seems you are setting your option headers where it should go the post params

Comment: @Raffobaffo That error is an obvious bug in the Go code. If changing domains "fixes" it, that means there's a domain-related bug in the Go service.

Comment: @Flimzy Cool. As said, I have no experience at all with go, but it just seems weird that with postman it works no? I still point out to the original poster to check the axios POST request, because there are no parameters and the place where to put the headers and other config is the third parameter, not the second.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok, but, if axios is sending out a request without the token header, Go would still throw some error about missing authentication token, or not? The error the OP mention is notAllowed, and to me makes sense for a response to a request missing a token..

Comment: I understand your point, but for what we do see, we see that the axios request is malformed, and that when the request is sent via postman it works. To me make definitively sense to add one line to see if the problem is in the OP code without bothering the Go developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a mistake in the axios request.
You are receiving a 403, that means you are not authorized (or sometimes something else, check the comments in the question and down here ).

As can be found in [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config), the post request looks like this:
`axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`.

It accepts the config (so the headers) as THIRD parameter, while you are setting it as second parameter. Add an empty FormData object as second param, and just shift your config to the third param.

```
const fakeData = new FormData();
const response = await this.$axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/v1/org/${params.organization}/kkms/${params.kkm}/closeShift`,
fakeData,
{
  headers : { 
               'token' : this.state.token.value
             }
});
```

Comment: Even there is a mistake in the client's code, this has nothing to do with the error message in the question which is a blooper on the server side: the server code is not allowed to fail no matter how botched a client's request is.

Comment: That said, I admire your desire to help the OP with a tangential problem but this still does not qualify as a proper answer to the question as asked. The question should either be closed or greatly reworked to include the actual Go code which fails.

Comment: From wikipedia: HTTP 403 is a HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden for some reason. The server understood the request, but will not fulfill it due to client-related issues.

Comment: I think you look my score, not my answers

Comment: I'd guess this is merely a byproduct of a misbehaving HTTP handler on the Go side. _Or_ the OP for some reason conflated two unrelated problems: a crash in a handler's code and the handler returning 403 in _some_ cases.

Comment: The problem is that you are talking about the code that you do not see, while I talk of the one that we can see, that has an error, that is not sending out any header with a token. 
Again, 403 unauthorized makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I think I got your point; both me and Flimzy were carried away with the «runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference» which is absolutely positively common error in (sloppy-written) Go code. Still, the OP have never indicated when it happens and whether it is at all linked with the problem they are facing. Hence I'm now inclined to think this particular question is not about Go at all but is really about `axios`. I now regret downvoting your answer. Can you edit it so I'd be able to upvote it back?

Comment: Great, thanks for agreeing with me. Of course, I will edit it again.

Comment: Thank you @Raffobaffo! I did exactly as you said. I guess we just change the request method to GET rather than POST since no need to send any data.

Comment: Great. Glad it worked. If you are not sending any data there, makes sense to send a get. I see the url is already pretty descriptive.